# Determine if the function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Determine if the function is Analytic:

$$f\left(x\right)=\ln\left(x^2+\sin\:\left(4x+y^2\right)+\sqrt{x-3}\right)+i\:\left(\tan\:\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{\sin\:\left(x^2-1\right)}\right)$$

$$f\left(x\right)=(\ln\left(x^2+\sin\:\left(4x+y^2\right)+\sqrt{x-3}\right))i+\:\left(\tan\:\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{\sin\:\left(x^2-1\right)}\right)$$

At the university the professor sent us these 2 exercises, although I was trying to solve them, I got to a point where I don't know what to do.

I know that for it to be analytic it has to fulfill the Cauchy-Rieman equations when making the derivative of the real part $u$ and the imaginary part (where $i$ is) $v$, but I can't find the solution to derive $u$ in the first and second exercises.

Comment: Please remove the photo and add the functions using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

By $f(x)$ do you mean $f(z=x+iy)$?
If yes, then here is the hint for the first one: As you mentioned Cauchy-Riemann equations should be held. Therefore taking $$v=\tan\:\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{\sin\:\left(x^2-1\right)},$$
you obtain that $v_y=0$ which should be equal to $u_x$.